# Web Push Notification Personalizada

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Gostaria de saber como faço uma `Push Notification` no navegador que seja personalizada por usuário. Saberiam me dizer como devo seguir? É possível gerar um `ID` único para aquele device que a pessoa está aceitando receber as notificações?

Lembrando que **não** estou desenvolvendo um APP `Android/IOS/WP`, e sim um **sistema web**. Desejo enviar as notificações via `browser`.

Obrigado!

Comment: Cara pesquisa ai sobre o OneSignal, utilizo ele e acho excelente para Push Notification, tanto web como mobile.

Comment: Relacionado: [Notificações de desktop - Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228487/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-desktop-javascript/228547#228547)