# Notificações de desktop - Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Preciso enviar notificações de desktop ao usuário, mesmo quando ele não estiver com o site aberto, porém só consigo chamar a notificação em eventos (click, load, change...). Como eu poderia enviar essas notificações?

```
Notification.requestPermission(function() {
                var notification = new Notification("Casa de Cambio Santos", {
                    icon: 'http://teste.png',
                    body: "Texto texto texto texto"
                });
                notification.onclick = function() {
                    window.open("http://teste.com.br");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Está usando wordpress? o Plugin OneSignal faz isso para você. Não atende? tente procurar algo como Web Push Notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a descrição que você passou você precisara usar [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/API_Push) ao invés de tão somente [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Utilizar_API_Notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es). Pense na `API` **Push** como uma **Notifications** com "esteroides".

Independente de seu site ser estático ou dinâmico esta `API` é `javascript` e roda no navegador do usuário, contudo é um pouco mais trabalhosa de implementar do que a **Notificatios**.

Esta `API` esta disponível em [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) e necessita de um **back-end** como serviço para de fato enviar notificações para o cliente (usuário).

Existe uma grande oferta de serviços (servidores) que fazem este trabalho de **back-end** para [Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/API_Push) gratuitos ou pagos que inclusive podem ter uma boa documentação para você implementar um **Service Worker** em seu site contudo se você possui um servidor (gerencia) pode ser uma boa ideia implementar seu próprio serviço e manter um controle total sobre o sistema de notificações.

Normalmente não gosto de postar respostas do tipo: **"siga este link aqui"** más, se fosse postar os códigos para implementar **Push** com o devido esclarecimento seria um post muito longo além do que não é preciso **"reinventar a roda"** com uma gama tão grande de bons materiais e boas fontes.

Então segue os links:

- Service Worker:

  - Especificação: [Mozila Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)
  - Uma simples introdução: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers?hl=pt-br)
  - Suporte: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=serviceworker)
- Push API:

  - Especificação: [Mozila Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/API_Push)
  - Exemplo pratico: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=pt-br) (muito bem detalhado)
  - Suporte: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=push)

O exemplo do site [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=pt-br) é muito bom más não ensina a criar um serviço próprio caso tenha interesse em mergulhar de cabeça podes começar dando uma olhada na lista de **libs** [hospedadas no GitHub](https://github.com/web-push-libs/) eu particularmente recomendo [web-push](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) feita para rodar em Node.

---

**edição:**

Um [Cookie Book sobre Push API](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/) (talvez o melhor que já li)